# Unable to run dotnetprojects WpfToolkit

Tags: datagrid, namespaces, xml-namespaces, wpftoolkit, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have a project which still uses Xceed WPF Toolkit DataGrid, and I want to upgrade it to https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfExtendedToolkit.

I have unistalled the Xceed nuget and installed this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetProjects.Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/

Once done that, I have removed these two lines from my XAML:

```
xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

And replaced them with these other two ones:

```
xmlns:xcdg="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid;assembly=DotNetProjects.Wpf.Extended.Toolkit"
xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=DotNetProjects.Wpf.Extended.Toolkit"
```

But it does not work. Both namespaces are not found in the assembly.

Anyone can help me to setup this, please?

Thank you